# what is keyword If Page.IsPostBack how can use it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What is this keyword how can use it?

```
If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
```

Comment: That's a bunch of keywords and a bunch of things that aren't keywords.

Comment: -1 This site can't help you with that answer, you need to read an asp.net book or take a class.  The postback is a very basic and fundamental building block to asp.net web pages.  If you don't understand it, you won't have a grasp on any of the other material.

Comment: @Wade I don't think that's entirely fair, I came from a long background of Classic ASP and such concepts that are fundamental blocks can be quite counter intuitive sometimes, but netherless this is an answer that could easily be googled.

Comment: It was not meant to be harsh and I apologize if it was.

Comment: @Wade not at all wasn't Harsh, was just pointing out that some things are not so obvious to others :)  Your point is fair.

Answer (score 5):

**IsPostBack**

Here is an overview of IsPostBack from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

It quotes:

> true if the page is being loaded in
>   response to a client postback;
>   otherwise, false.

The postback is useful, say for example you have a `Literal` control on the page, and the code on page load sets the `Literal.text += "hello";`  If you have a button on that page, and press it, the text of the literal will get longer and longer, `hellohellowhello`, if you wrap the code in (c# example):

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack){
    Literal.text += "hello";
}
```

The Literal text now wont expand when the button is pressed.

**Other Notes**

Instead of:

```
If(Page.IsPostBack = False)
```

Do:

```
If(!Page.IsPostBack)
```

This is logically the same and is generally accepted to be a better way of writing the statement.

Also you marked the question C#, but the If syntax you used indicates you are writing it in VB.net, not C#.

Comment: I am not argueing that it is a better way of writing it as I write mine in c# that way as well but last time I did work on vb.net !(read bang) does not work you have to use the keyword not.  That may have changed in recent versions though as I was working in a 2.0 app on vs2005.

Comment: @Chad, you're probably right, it's been a long time since I've done VB!  Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

Gets a value indicating whether the page is being loaded in response to a client postback, or if it is being loaded and accessed for the first time.

Return Values:
true if the page is being loaded in response to a client postback; otherwise, false.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `IsPostBack` tells you whether or not the page has been Posted Back, meaning "server side" button has been clicked.

You can "use" it by reading its value and acting upon it.

It's useful for example when you add controls dynamically to your page, so you don't have to add them when it's a PostBack.

Official documentation already been posted by others, look there for any further or technical details.